# Remove Item from Cart using before add product Plugin

Tags: magento2.3, cart, plugin, quoteitem

I'm using magento 2.3 and i'm trying to Remove an especifc **Item** from **Cart**, using beforAddProduct **Plugin**.

The problem is that i don't know how to remove the **Item** from **Cart**.

It shows the following error: ***Invalid argument supplied for foreach()***

> Plugin code:

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class PreventAddToCart
{
    protected $messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        LoggerInterface $logger
        )
    {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct(Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
        // $this->messageManager->addWarning("ITEM NÃO DISPONÍVEL");
        // throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__("ha ha"));
        // return [$productInfo,$requestInfo];
        
        $data = $subject->getData();
        
        $itemId = $productInfo->getId();
        $subject->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        
        $items = $subject->getAllItems();

        foreach($items as $item){
            $txt = "\n.SKU --> ".$item->getSku();
            $this->logger->log('DEBUG', $txt);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: is the cart instance of class \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart?

can you do a var_dump($items); before the foreach loop starts to see the value you have in the variable $items?

Comment: Yes, the Cart instance is right, but when a tried var_dump($items) the page returns HTTP ERROR 500, and there is no error message on the debug.

Comment: Ok, i solved the HTTP ERROR 500, tried the var_dump($items) it don't shows anything, tried JSON_ENCODE($items) it returns NULL.

Comment: i would add a check on $items

if (!empty($items) && is_iterable($items)) {
 foreach($items as $item){
            $txt = "\n.SKU --> ".$item->getSku();
            $this->logger->log('DEBUG', $txt);
        }
}